# DevExpress Report - How to have a band expand to fit contents?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I have a DevExpress report, which contains an XRLabel. Sometimes the content of the label goes onto multiple lines, so I've set `Multiline` property to `true` as well as the `CanGrow` property.

However, I also need the Band it's contained in to expand with it to allow room for the extra lines. It's a TopMargin band. (Which doesn't have a `CanGrow` property)

I have tried creating a script to achieve this but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
private void TopMargin_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    TopMargin.Height = 100 + uxLblMarginTopLeft.Height;
}
```

Also, on debugging this, I see the `uxLblMarginTopLeft.Height` seems to only give the value of what it was originally set to in Visual Studio property manager, not the height after it expanded due to multiple lines.

Normally the label is bound to a value, but I have the same problem if I set the value to a long string from within the script.

**EDIT**

I managed to change the height programmatically by putting it in the BeforePrint event of the report itself rather than the Band's (as was done above) and using this code:

```
private void TBaseReport_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    XtraReport report = (XtraReport) sender;
    report.Bands[BandKind.TopMargin].Height = 200;
    Console.WriteLine("Label Height is : |" + uxLblMarginTopLeft.Height + "|");
}
```

But, the height of the label remains as 19, and not its expanded height.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also asked a similar question on the DevExpress site, and got this answer:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T359777

Basically measures the text string and calculates the height like that. It appears there is no way of getting the "real" height of the label.